# Application not compatible to 12 inch tablet

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-screen-support

My Application not compatible with 12.2 inch screen.

In my manifest I used the following support-screen attributes.

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

The application intention is to support only tablets.
What the thing(s) I missed here.
If need more details please let me know,I am ready to provide.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

Comment: @Yvette In play store the application not compatible with Samsung Galaxy Tab Pro(12.2 inch).